# How do I limit the values I can save?

Tags: string, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm currently working on a Registration form where all the details of a student are save in a text file.

In one of my fields, I have a `combobox` list of all the school he/she can select.

I populated the `combobox` using a `textfile`.

The format of these values are for example: (code~school name) SCH001~Saint Thomas College

**Question - how do I limit the values I can save?
example - I want only the school code to be saved without the name of school: SCH001**

Here's how I save the fields in a text file:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRegister.Click
    Dim firstname, lastname, email, mobile, level, currentschool, currenttrack, institution1, institution2, institution3, institution4, institution5, institution6, courses1, courses2, courses3 As String
    firstname = txtFName.Text
    lastname = txtLName.Text
    email = txtEmail.Text
    mobile = txtMobile.Text
    level = cmbLevel.Text
    currentschool = cmbCurrentSchool.Text
    currenttrack = cmbCurrentTrack.Text
    institution1 = cmbInstitution1.Text
    institution2 = cmbInstitution2.Text
    institution3 = cmbInstitution3.Text
    institution4 = cmbInstitution4.Text
    institution5 = cmbInstitution5.Text
    institution6 = cmbInstitution6.Text
    courses1 = cmbCourse1.Text
    courses2 = cmbCourse2.Text
    courses3 = cmbCourse3.Text

    Using sw As StreamWriter = File.AppendText("C:\Users\jmrosales\Documents\RegistrationForm\Registered.txt")
        sw.WriteLine(firstname & "~" & lastname & "~" & email & "~" & mobile & "~" & level & "~" & currentschool & "~" & currenttrack & "~" & institution1 & "~" & institution2 & "~" & institution3 & "~" & institution4 & "~" & institution5 & "~" & institution6 & "~" & courses1 & "~" & courses2 & "~" & courses3)
    End Using
    MsgBox("Registration Complete!")
End Sub
```

I hope you guys understand what i'm trying to say.
I'm just new here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in two ways:

1. Using `.Split()`
2. Using `.Substring()`

---

1. Using `.Split()`
   Here's what your code will look like:

   `currentschool = cmbCurrentSchool.Text.Split("~")`

This will return two strings, **"SCH001"** and **"Saint Thomas College"**.
But since you need only the Code, put `(0)` at the end of the code above:

`currentschool = cmbCurrentSchool.Text.Split("~")(0)`

Further you can add `c` in the above snippet like:

`currentschool = cmbCurrentSchool.Text.Split("~"c)(0)`

This would specify `~` is a *character*.

---

2. using `.Substring()`
   This will only work if it's sure that your code will always be **6 character** (3 for SCH and rest 3 for the number-code)

   `currentschool = cmbCurrentSchool.Text.Substring(0,6)`

Here, 0 means start picking the character from **1st** position and 6 means get **six characters** to get a new string.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for correcting my code, it was a typo on my part and i didn't even realize it!

Comment: +1 for explaining the answer in depth, which I didn't. Also you can do  `("~"c)` in  `("~")` to specify it is a character

Comment: thank you guys for answering. really helped a lot. my problem is finally solved.

Comment: you're welcome :) don't forget to vote the answer xD

Comment: I do not mean to be rude or anything, and while you did correct Nobody's typo you also pretty much wrote an exact copy of our answers. -- Don't get me wrong though... I appreciate that you're taking part in the helper side of the community, but when there already are other answers about something writing another one with only minor improvements is just unnecessary (not saying that you did this intentionally, just wanted to give you a heads up). Happy coding (and answering)!

Comment: Well I read somehwere in Meta that "if you see that a question has already been answered, try to take a time and write your answer with proper description so that people will be more attracted with your answer even if it was not the first one". And I didn't copy your answers, its just that the process is the same to do the work required :)

Comment: Well aware of both your statements. I didn't think you _actually_ copied our answers, and whoever said that on Meta is right: it is good to write an answer with a proper description. _However_ I (personally) also think one shouldn't overdo it. Your answer is good, but it is also _**very**_ similar to ours. Most of what you wrote we'd already mentioned.

Comment: Again I'm not trying to be rude or patronizing, and I'm _**definitely not**_ saying that you should stop trying write better answers, but in my _**personal**_ opinion perhaps you should focus on making a bit bigger changes? -- I realize that for this simple question there isn't much more to add, it's just that I've seen people get mad for far less... Just a word of advice from my experience! :)

Comment: haha yeah exactly! there is nothing more or better and efficient way to do it. so i thought i'd rather explain what's going on in the code!

Comment: No hate! Happy coding guys!

Comment: well what really matters is it it helped the OP :D

Answer (score 2):

Presuming that the school code would follow **exactly 6 characters** as in this  *SCH001~Saint Thomas College*, you can use `Substring`:

```
currentschool = cmbCurrentSchool.Text.Substring(0,6) '6 means 6 characters to be cut from cmbCurrentSchool to currentschool
```

If here `currentschool` stores the schoolcode.

Else, you can use `Split`:

```
currentschool = cmbCurrentSchool.Text.Split("~")(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The most simple answer would be to split the string at `~` and just return the part you need:

```
If cmbCurrentSchool.Text.Contains("~") Then 'A check to avoid possible errors.
    currentschool = cmbCurrentSchool.Text.Split("~"c)(0) '0 means that we should get the first item of the array, thus "SCH001".
Else
    currentschool = cmbCurrentSchool.Text
End If
```

`cmbCurrentSchool.Text.Split("~"c)` will return an array of two strings:

```
"SCH001~Saint Thomas College"  ->  {"SCH001", "Saint Thomas College"}
```

**Documentation:**

- [**`String.Split()` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx)